# Adding extra n rows at the end of a dataframe of a certain value

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with currently 22 rows

```
index value
  0     23
  1     22
  2     19
 ...
 21     20
```

to this dataframe, i want to add 72 rows to make the dataframe exactly 100 rows. So i need to fill loc[22:99] but with a certain value, let's say 100.

I tried something like this

```
uncon_dstn_2021['balance'].loc[22:99] = 100
```

but did not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do reindex

```
out = df.reindex(df.index.tolist() + list(range(22, 99+1)), fill_value = 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pd.concat`:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'balance': [100]*(100-len(df))})], ignore_index=True)
print(df1)

# Output
     balance
0          1
1         14
2         11
3         11
4         10
..       ...
96       100
97       100
98       100
99       100

[100 rows x 1 columns]
```